# WSO2 SCIM2.0 API GET USERS empty result

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured [ldap readonly](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-read-only-ldap-user-store/) user store and I can see the users from this US while using the admin panel.
But when I try to call the [SCIM 2.0 API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/using-the-scim-2.0-rest-apis/#get-get-users-user-listingfiltering) to get users, I always get an empty result. What might be the problem?

Request:

`GET https://wso2:9443/scim2/Users/?domain=mydomain`

Response:

```
    {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "startIndex": 1,
      "itemsPerPage": 0,
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: have you configured LDAP as secondary user store ?

Comment: Yes, it's configured as secondary user store.

Answer (score 2):

**Enable SCIM for the userstore**

First of all, please make sure that you have enabled scim for that userstore. Bydefault, scim is not enabled for ReadOnly LDAP userstore. By adding the following config in deployment.toml file, you can enable scim.

```
[user_store]
scim_enabled = true
```

If the issue still persists after adding the above config, verify the following claim mapping.

**Configure a mapped attribute for User ID claim.**

For SCIM, we need a unique ID for each user to identify separately. When you are creating users from WSO2 IS on a SCIM enabled userstore, we create a random ID for the new users and store in the "http://wso2.org/claims/userid" claim which is mapped to "**scimId**" attribute.

I presume that you have plugged in a read-only LDAP userstore with an existing set of users. So you may not have values for "scimId" attribute on this particular user store. That may be a root cause of this issue. So this users might not have the **scimId**, hence does not have any unique User ID

**Verify**

1. Claims > List > "http://wso2.org/claims".
2. goto edit view of the claim named "User ID" Enable support by default for this claim.
3. Now go to the list users page and view the profile of a user who belongs to the LDAP userstore
4. Please check whether the attribute "User ID" is having a value or not.
5. Optionally, you can check are there any
   values mapped for "http://wso2.org/claims/userid"  directly from the
   ReadOnlyLDAP side
   [image]

If you have the above issue, (there is no any mapped attribute for "http://wso2.org/claims/userid" claim),

**Solution**

1. Find a unique attribute unique among the existing users from ReadOnly LDAP user store
2. You can go to the above-mentioned claim edit page and click on "Add Attribute Mapping" under "Mapped Attribute (s)*". 
   [image]
3. Then select the user store domain, enter the unique attribute name and update.
4. check whether now the User ID attribute of the user profile is not empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did all of the above. Now this request is executed after 70 seconds with http 500 status.

Comment: Log: `[2020-02-26 11:56:01,175] [b7463527-ca51-41a6-803c-c61d98e879b4] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when called by method getRoleListOfUsers with 1 length of Objects and argTypes [class [Ljava.lang.String;]`

Comment: Response: `{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
  ],
  "detail": "Error occurred while retrieving SCIM user information",
  "status": "500"}`

Comment: This is a general error. Please add the whole stack trace. Also attach the logs with debug logs enabled in component org.wso2.carbon.user.core. Refer the following documentation for logging guide https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/monitoring-logs/

Comment: Debug logs enabled: https://gist.github.com/okondrashin/14f8339f7390c9fe9f4da57d35182133

Comment: `username` is configured for attribute mapping for `User ID`

Comment: May be useful. When I create request `https://wso2:9443/scim2/Users/?domain=mydomain&attributes=uid&count=10` (with count) i have empty response again (but without error).

Comment: Do you have a unique username attribute in the userstore? Check whether the userstore supports the attribute and map that attribute

Comment: Yes. It's done. `User ID` is mapped to `username` attribute from ldap. It's unique.

Comment: I have another request with pagination and have the question described it his gist: https://gist.github.com/okondrashin/6c0a0446ab35e1bac2b91810481cef08 (May be helpful to resolve the issue)

Comment: Some useful info: it's work for 5.7.0 (result is not empty) WSO2IS, but not work since 5.8.0

Comment: And it works for SCIM1 API in my current version 5.9.0 (result is not empty). So, the problem is reproduced only for SCIM2 API since 5.8.0.